# JQGrid on Bootstrap 4 (which was officially released)

Tags: jqgrid

Does anyone know if jqgrid will integrate with the officially released version of Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1):

The current code of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) on GitHub supports released version of Bootstrap4. One need just use `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` instead of `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)). Additionally, one should don't forget to use full jQuery, like `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`, instead of slim version (`jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`).

Comment: Where can we find which version of bootstrap 3/ 4 is supported for the free jqGrid?

Comment: @plchia: Free jqGrid supports both bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4. To inform free jqGrid, which CSS classes should be used one have to use `guiStyle` parameter. `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` means bootstrap 3 and `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` means bootstrap 4. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) for corresponding code examples.